# Must all unitary eigenvalues be non-defective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a real square matrix. Say some of its eigenvalues are unitary complex numbers, but it also has other eigenvalues that are not unitary (they may be real or complex). **Must the unitary eigenvalues always be non-defective?**

My reasoning is the following: let $S$ be the subspace that is spanned by all eigenvectors corresponding to unitary eigenvalues. Then the projection of $A$ to $S$ is a unitary matrix and therefore all its eigenvalues are non-defective. However, I'm confused as to whether it is possible for the original $A$ to have generalized eigenvectors outside of the space $S$.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: What if $A$ is the companion matrix of $(x^2+1)^2$?